# random font for website text?

Tags: php, html, css, random, fonts

I've seen lots of methods for generating random font colours, but how would I go about using a random font from a list of fonts (or just totally random) for a section of text on my website?

Comment: Are you talking about random colours or random fonts or both? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a random entry from a list in PHP like this:

```
$fonts = array("Helvetica", "Arial", "Comic Sans", "Tahoma");
shuffle($fonts);
$randomFont = array_shift($fonts);
```

and then just echo `$randomFont` wherever you want to override the class. Perhaps in a `<style>` tag inline in your document

Comment: would the php have to be in the same div as the style tag? i'm just getting to grips with php..

Comment: The PHP could be anywhere in the page before you want to get at `$randomFont` and where you need it just add `<?php echo $randomFont ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of font names.

Then when you are setting the color of the text:

```
var array_ofcolors = ['red', 'blue',...]
obj.style.color = 
      array_ofcolors[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_ofcolors.length)]
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/EJAmv/

And you can do the same for fonts: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/EJAmv/1/

```
var array_offonts = ["Helvetica", "Arial", "Comic Sans", "Tahoma"]
obj.style.fontFamily = 
      array_offonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_offonts.length)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $font =   array(
      "Arial", 
      "monospace", 
      "Comic Sans MS", 
      "Times", 
      "Lucida Sans", 
      "Verdana", 
      "Helvetica"
    );//insert ^there another Fonts
?>

<a style="font-family: <?php echo $font[rand(0,6)]; ?>;" href="#"><h1>Encrypted array <.../> </h1></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Webpage, and I Think it's easy:

```
<?php 
$font = 
    array(
      "Arial", 
      "monospace", 
      "Comic Sans MS", 
      "Times", 
      "Lucida Sans", 
      "Verdana", 
      "Helvetica"
    );//insert ^there another Fonts
?>
<style> 
 *{ 
   font-family: <?php echo($font[rand(1,7)]); ?>;
  } 
</style>
```