# Random font in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm searching for a way to show random fonts on my WordPress page. I found two related answers here:

[random font for website text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985325/random-font-for-website-text)

[How do I generate a random font to a line of text every time page is refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862759/how-do-i-generate-a-random-font-to-a-line-of-text-every-time-page-is-refreshed)

But I don't know exactly how to implement them in WordPress. I tried the JS method in WordPress, but it seems that it didn't worked. 
I'm new to PHP/JS, so if anyone have an idea I would be very thankful.

Comment: Can you pls add some code samples you had done in JS

Comment: Hey Samuel, 

I just put the code form the js.question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985325/random-font-for-website-text) in my custom JS field in the WP-theme. 

Best regards.
Artur

Comment: You're telling me every time I hit a new page on your site I'm going to have to download another 100-250KB webfont?

Comment: Hey ceejayoz, It will be just three different fonts. So I hope just three times, right?

Best regards, Artur

Comment: There is an accepted PHP answer for the first SO question you linked to, so: do you have an actual question? We're not going to help you write a wordpress plugin, that's what the internet at large is for. Find a tutorial on writing a WP plugin that lets you change head/body content, and then apply what you learned from the answer in the first question you linked to.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike.